# How to have single-slug behave like a normal page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm making a website in WordPress, and I'm using a plugin ACF PRO. I'm doing the entire site with flexible content, so the WordPress site is like a page builder.

Everything is fine, however, I came to a point where I need to have same functionality for single-[custom-post-type], so I can "Add row", header, footer etc... on it, but I can't figure out on how to do it.

I know that it's possible, because e.g if you look at this site here: https://rolleragency.co.uk/our-projects/

You can see that it works. I know they are using flexible content because I worked on that site and I did there what I wanted. I can't remember how to do that.

I think I had to use a Tempate Page? Or? I can't remember.

THe site is built entirely on flexible content, so everything there is modular and it's like a drag and drop, but how do I do that on single-slug?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a page template, yes.

So something like `page-projects.php` then in WordPress admin you would have a page called `Projects`.

The template you created should be automatically applied to this page. If it doesn't for some reason you can choose which template WP should use on the right side when editing a page.

Now, you can add whatever code you need to the `page-projects.php`. And also any fields you may need for that page you can set up in ACF by telling ACF to apply those fields to pages that use projects template.

This is how I would and did do it on several occasions :)

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure about the page-project.php. Isn't that just a normal page? I do have a normal page where I display projects with a Custom Post Type Query. However, if I click the project, it will go to a single-[custom-post-type].php page, how can I customize that like a normal page? Take for example domain.com/projects - i have that, and the projects are displayed. When user clicks a project domain.com/projects/[project-name] how can I customize the project-name page?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you already have singe-[custom-post-type].php then you customize it there. No?

Comment: singe-[custom-post-type].php - I want to customize it via admin dashboard. I'm using fflexible content, and my page php looks like this                                .       <?php 

if( have_rows('template_blocks') ):

    while ( have_rows('template_blocks') ) : the_row();

        if( get_row_layout() == 'header_page' ):
           get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'header-page' );

        elseif( get_row_layout() == 'header_main' ):
           get_template_part( 'templates/section', 'header-main' );                   .   Said that, the entire site is modular drag and drop

Comment: So I go to my pages, and I have 'Add row' with flexible content, and that's how I build the pages. This is the repo, that's how I build it - https://github.com/AurelianSpodarec/aurelianMegaPortfolio2018

Comment: Ok, so you are not getting the "Add row" button on your project items? Did you say in ACF that you want to add those fields to projects custom post type?

Comment: Hmmm. But there is not page for sinlge-[custom-post-type].php though, is it? We can edit the pages we add via the admin dashboard, and we will have the "Add row" right? Yes xd I have registered a post type projects(like in comment below) and I can add new projects, and with Query take them out. However, if I click on it, it will go to single custom post type, which there is no page for that in the admin area.

Comment: function projects_post_type() {
      $args = array(
          'public'    => true,
          'label'     => __( 'Projects'),
          'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book',
      );
      register_post_type( 'projects', $args );
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'projects_post_type' );

Comment: Here, I put this into images, but look at if from the bottom to top: https://imgur.com/a/b8Ajm   

You see the header there, because I included the get_header manually to all pages, but the footer is , for example, added with flexible content as the footer might differ.

Comment: I think, in short, is, how can I add ACF to single.php  page, when there is no single page in the adminarea?

Comment: There is no single page in admin yes. And there is no single-custom-post-type in admin. 

BUT there is the actuall posts. What you have on image number 3. So your fields should be visible when you click on "Dorota Dishes" for example.

And in ACF you should have Post Type ... is equal to .... Project (or whatever you called your post type) .

Comment: Yes, I need to select the Template Blocks to be equal to the page, and project. However, if I do that... every single project will require me to repeat the process of setting the header, the footer and everything. We don't want that, it should be automated. That's why the single-[customposttype].php should be select, so when I change it in once place, it will look for every single Project. So far I made it like you mean, but that just won't work. You want to change layout in future and you would need to go to every single project to change the layout, because it only assigns to that single pro

Comment: // add_filter('acf/location/rule_match/single_template', 'acf_location_rules_match_user', 10, 3);
// function acf_location_rules_match_user( $match, $rule, $options )
// {
//  $match_template = get_page_by_path('single-');

//  if($rule['operator'] == "==")
//  {
//   $match = ($match_template);
//  } 
//  else if($rule['operator'] == "!=") 
//  {
//   $match = ($match_template);
//  }

//  return $match;
// }

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/custom-location-rules/ - I think this is what I need to do, to add rule, so when I chenge it in one place, it should change everyhwere, as it's going to be the single-posttype.php or? Not sure how to do that either.

Comment: Why can't you just define the header or any other compnent in single-[custom-post-type].php? ACF fields should be only for content that will be changed form project to project. Everything that stays the same should be defined in template.

Comment: Because that's how I'm building the site. It has to be modular. If the client want's to re-strategize the layout, he can do so. Bare in min I'm using Flexible Content with ACF, which is a drag and drop page builder like. So it's essential for me to be able to do a single page. Maybe the client decides in future that he want's to change the call to action block that's just above the footer, or maybe he doesn't want to have a footer and the action block, but just a form. ANd it should reflect on every single-post-type.php. People have done this, and that's how agencies also work, so I'm learning

Comment: On how to do it, because when I apply for a job id have to know how to do this in the first place anyway, it's a new way of doing it. In the previosu job I did this, but I'm not 100% sure how they did it as I was just adding new features and pages. This site here I'm doing for my self to test this, and so far it works all good, apart from the single-custom-post-type.php - you see this agency for example, - https://www.designbyday.co.uk/flexibility-flexible-content/ and if you google this you'd see a lot more on this. 

I like it, very modular, that's how I need to do it.

Comment: Good luck with that. I understand where you are coming from, but I think that is a wrong approach. I worked at a couple of agencies and we have always avoided putting that much control in the users hand. I remember just one site that has been done that way and it was a nightmare. Anyway... getting off-topic here...... I guess you could create a page called something like "Project Header". Then you can create a template project-header.php. Put this in: `<?php /* Template name: Project header */ ?>` . Make "Project header" page use project-header.php as a template.

Comment: Now you can do whatever you want on that page. ACF, flexible content whatever. Now you just need to include content of that page on your sinle-[custom-post-type].php template. Try using this method: https://clicknathan.com/web-design/how-to-include-a-specific-pages-content-in-a-wordpress-theme-without-a-plugin/ . Anyway this solution is so icky that I need to take a shower :) . But I can't think of anything better ATM. Sorry.

Comment: It depends. Where I worked, at a good agency that's expanding rapidly, they use this. Another angecy that I'm looking at to apply, they also do this. THis is more and more common. It's not new. The Template Name, I'm using ACF Flexible Content, I don't have to do that xd It's very neat. I'll try the other possible solution for the sinlge-[custom-post-type].php page .